# Are Telegram Bot API Rate Limits for Messages Also Applicable to Channels?

Tags: bots, telegram, limit

We've developed a bot that forwards user messages to a single tracker channel. We experience delays. Can it be due to rate limits on bot posting in the channel? [Telegram FAQ: Broadcasting to Users](https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq#broadcasting-to-users) says:

> your bot will not be able to send more than 20 messages per minute to the same group

Does this apply to channels too?